# Obtaining table data in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to obtain the contents of the large table in the following webpage: http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01/gamelog/2013/.
I want to then save the contents to a spreadsheet. All of this is to be done in Perl.
I'm not really sure how to proceed with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if you take a look above the large table, you can click on CSV, which I believe (possibly?) would make it easier for me to obtain the table data and put it into an Excel spreadsheet. Any advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: Using the CSV data would indeed be simpler than scraping the page, but what have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a "here, do this for me" website. You need to show us what you've tried first. Once you do that, tons of people will be glad to assist.

Comment: get the CSV with LWP::Simple getstore() function?

Comment: [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TableExtract) is [beautiful](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html).

Comment: I don't think you can `GET` the CSV data. It is generated using JavaScript. If you want to only access the data on that one page, click the CSV link, and copy & paste the CSV into Excel. Otherwise, use `HTML::TableExtract`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür : I didn't actually open the page, but I doubt that the JavaScript generates CSV from HTML...there is likely involved a URL that returns more raw data (possibly XML). Or the HTML table itself might be generated from the AJAX call, and the CSV is a variation on that call. Some JavaScript debugging with Firefox/Firebug would probably reveal that URL.

Comment: @runrig Nope, from what I can tell, the `get_csv_output` function actually walks the table rows and converts them to CSV.

Comment: Ok I will try HTML::TableExtract. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the HTML file locally, you can parse it using [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) and import the tab-separated file into Excel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);
use open qw(:std :utf8);

# see http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html

use File::Slurp qw( read_file );
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $content = read_file 'index.html', binmode => ':utf8';

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(attribs => {id => 'pgl_basic'});

$te->parse($content);
my ($table) = $te->tables;

for my $row ($table->rows) {
    next if $row->[0] eq 'Rk';
    print join("\t", map { defined($_) ? $_ : '' } @$row), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without having the html files locally (i.e. just straight from the website)? The reason for this is that I may want to look at a couple of players and just extract their stats (i.e. the table) to a spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: Of course it is, but I am not sure if the site's TOS allows spidering like that. Plus, even if it is allowed, I do not like to hit the site multiple times during development every time I make a change. You can use `HTTP::Tiny` or `LWP::Simple` to get the content.

Comment: Hi again, don't know if anyone will see this, but i have another web page (from the same site) that I want to obtain the tables of. Each player has many tables, but I only want the Per Game table. Here is an example: http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cartevi01.html#per_game::none . Is there anyway to do this in Perl? Whereby I just obtain this one specific table? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the data as a CSV, you can open it directly in Excel, no transformation required.

Parsing HTML is tricky and error prone, because what constitutes valid HTML can be quite ugly.

If you *really* need to write an XLS file, after reading the CSV (for instance, by using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV)), you can write to the binary XLS file format using something like [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel)

Note, I've used [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV) before -- it's pretty reasonable.  I have no experience with [WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel).

Comment: I think I have the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel package installed, so I wil try that! Thanks